# How convex hull and SAT algorithms will be useful in details below?

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

In the two-ball game, n > 4 kickers are positioned on the playing field and do not move (i.e.\ change their locations) during the game. Four of the players are distinguished: two of them, denoted as s1 and s2, are called starting players, and two others, denoted as t1 and t2, are called terminal players. At the beginning, player s1 has got a white ball and s2 possesses a black ball. Then each starting player can kick the ball directly to the corresponding terminal player but he can also kick the ball to any other player on the field and this player can pass the ball to the next one, and so on. The aim is that at the end the white ball is in possession of t1 and the black ball in possession of t2. So, it seems the game is quite simple. However, to avoid ball collisions, the constraint of the game is that no ball trajectories cross each other and that no player (including starting and terminal ones) has more than one ball contact. For simplicity, we assume the trajectory of a ball moving from one player to the next one is a line segment.

Note:This is problem on spoj and I need just suggestions which algorithm are required to solve this efficiently and why they are required.Link for problem is [SPOJ TBGAME Question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TBGAME/)

Comment: Assume both `s1` and `t1` are on the convex hull. This means there is no way 'around' line segment `(s1, t1)`. In what situations can you still come from `s2` to `t2` then? Now, assume that not both `s1` and `t1` are on the convex hull. How can the convex hull then help you to get from `s2` to `t2` then?

Comment: It will be second convex hull and we will check if they intersect or not.But how to decide which convex hull contains both s1 and t1 and excludes any single of s2 or t2 or excludes both but does not includes both? I am confused still not able to think properly.Any other way for this other than convex hull if it is not the way as I think it might be?